# Can we include delays in structural architecture?

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to simulate EXOR using NOR gates. I have written the following logic for EXOR gate. Now, my nor2 is defined with 4 ns delay.

```
ENTITY ex IS
    PORT (a, b : IN BIT; c : OUT BIT);
END ex;

ARCHITECTURE structure OF ex IS

    SIGNAL tmp1, tmp2, tmp3, tmp4: BIT;
    COMPONENT nor2 PORT (x, y : IN BIT; z : OUT BIT); END COMPONENT;
BEGIN

    u0: nor2 PORT MAP (a, a, tmp1);

    u1: nor2 PORT MAP (b, b ,tmp2);

    u2: nor2 PORT MAP (tmp1,tmp2,tmp3);

    u3: nor2 PORT MAP (b, a, tmp4);

    u4: nor2 PORT MAP (tmp3, tmp4, c);

END structure;
```

I know that `tmp1`, `tmp2` and `tmp4` will change signals after 4 ns after `a` or `b` changes. I also notice that `tmp3` and hence `c` change after 4 ns (because `nor2` has 4 ns delay[`c <= a nor b after 4ns`]). But I want `tmp3` to reflect the change after 8 ns as per the proper logic and `c` after 12 ns. This will give me the proper output for `EXOR`. My question is how do I introduce a delay in structural architecture? Is there a way to do it? I tried to search but did not find any and wait doesn't work, it keeps giving me syntax error (wait for 8ns). Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the simulation result. It seems wrong because `nor` is a [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) operator.

Suppose that

```
a = '0'
b = '1'
```

then

```
tmp1 = '1' (a nor a)
tmp2 = '0' (b nor b)
tmp4 = '0' (b nor a)
tmp3 = '0' (tmp1 nor tmp2)
c    = '1' (tmp3 nor tmp4)
```

Now `b` changes to '0',

```
tmp1 = '1' remains unchanged
tmp2 = '1' after 4 ns
tmp4 = '1' after 4 ns
tmp3 = '0' remains unchanged (regardless of b because of short-circuit evaluation)
c    = '0' after 8 ns (not 12 ns because it only waits for tmp4 in this case)
```

Comment: I traced the with all the combinations of a and b. But, I got the same result as what you said. But, I want c to reflect the change only after a and b change. I change a and b after 10 ns. When I see the waveform, tmp3 and tmp4 are 0 initially and after 4 ns c changes to 1. Which is as per expected because a and b are also 0. But before a and b change their values to 0 and 1, tmp values change and hence c changes to 0 but a and b are still 0. I am expecting c to change only after a and b change so I want to introduce delay. Otherwise the waveform looks very confusing and unlike EXOR gate.

Comment: I have the waveform if you want me to post it.

Comment: @San See [here](http://www.ida.liu.se/~TDTS01/lectures/13/lect3.frm.pdf) and   also [here](http://www.gmvhdl.com/delay.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your model to a VITAL compliant one (IEEE Std 1076.4 VITAL (VHDL Inititative Towards ASIC libraries) but that might be a bit overkill for your purposes.  The standard characterizes the various types of delays, in this case combinatoric, where an output is dependent on a transition on an input.

For your top level model ex the delay on the c output is dependent on the longer of the delay from A to C or B to C.  Note the VITAL standard also can track 0->1 delays separately from 1->0 delays.

Applying an abstract delay model for ex requires tracing delay paths through the various nor gates to calculate the A to C or B to C delays.

A VITAL compliant delay model allows you to apply Standard Delay Format (SDF) delay files to a design models with compliant tools much as generics apply timing or other model characterization.

For your purposes because you have characterized the delays through the various nor gates barring trace parasitics, you could use an intermediary value where C is output  from the last nor gate now, and assign that to C after a delay controlled by A or B.

For characterizing delays, you can treat ex as a black box, providing delays at the macro level.

You appear to be anticipating no routing delays and symmetric 0->1 and 1->0 delays.

Something along the lines of an ordered list longer to shorter controlling delays

If A'event then C <= intermediary after AC_DELAY else
                     intermediary after BC_DELAY;  -- B'event

You can apply this at the finer level than macro, but it's not needed when individual nor gate outputs aren't used to determine some other output.

Comment: Do I have to use VITAL to introduce delay? Does this mean I cannot introduce delay in the code I posted(structural architecture)? I am new to vhdl. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: VITAL in the method silicon vendors use to apply Standard Delay Format (now IEEE Std 1497-2001) timing information to post place and route structural models of designs for VHDL simulation. SDF is the lingua franca CAD tools use to convey this timing information. There's nothing stopping you from applying timing to a VHDL design representation by another method, although it will limit the usefulness of such a design description to a third party or in representing different layouts or processes.